# Support for XML in Google Cloud Endpoint

Tags: xml, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-endpoints, google-cloud-endpoints-v2

After going through documentations and quick-start tutorials available for Google cloud Endpoint it feels like it currently supports json, where as Google Cloud Storage has support for both json and XML. I wanted to know if Google endpoint supports XML? in case I missed it in the ref documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Cloud Endpoint service definition is based on [Open API v2 version, also know as swagger 2](https://swagger.io/specification/v2/).

This specification is only in yaml format and you don't have the capability to use XML for this definition.

Anyway, today, there is a lot of libraries/frameworks that implement the Open API specification to generate automatically the API spec from your code, or to generate code stub from an existing API spec. It's one of the most popular standard today.

**EDIT**

According with your comment, if you want to add a body in XML, is up to you. It's out of Cloud Endpoint scope, where are on pure HTTP protocol here.

If your XML is too long, too complex because you have double quote and simple quote (and you have to escape them correctly,...), you can do this

- Put your XML in a file, with a name like `body.xml`
- Use file reference in curl `--data @body.xml`

Comment: Actually I wanted to take different approach, like for example while making the request to the cloud endpoint  in json format 
`
curl --request POST \
     --header "content-type:application/json" \
     --data '{"message":"hello world"}' \
     "http://echo-api.endpoints.<PROJECT_ID>:80/echo?key=${ENDPOINTS_KEY}"
` 

I want to do in XML format, something like this:
`
curl --request POST \
     --header "content-type:application/xml" \
     --data '<message>hello world</message>' \
     "http://echo-api.endpoints.<PROJECT_ID>:80/echo?key=${ENDPOINTS_KEY}" 
`

Comment: Ah ok, you want to post the body as XML format. so, what's your issue? I put a tip into the edit of my answer

Comment: Yes, I did try out in the way you mentioned in the comment, but still its the same problem, I get error message as 
`{
  "code": 500,
  "message": "Exception: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'"
}` 

Even though while configuring endpoint i have made following changes in the openapi.yaml file
`consumes:
- "application/xml"
produces:
- "application/xml"`

Comment: Does it work when you call directly your API without using endpoint?

Comment: I just tested, and as I said, there is no issue, it's not managed by Cloud Endpoint and the XML data are correct in input and output. Share a part of your API spec if you need more help.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I tried out with different back-end code and got the desired result. Thank you for the input! Its been great help!